# Converting Firebase json to Java object

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Ever since I started working with Firebase Real time database, trivial tasks are becoming increasingly difficult.

I have the following JSON structure in the Firebase DB.

```
{
    "EmailId": "sample.co@email.com",
    "Locations": {
        "-Kci2Ov9_lI2d5RUnvYT": {
            "Latitude": "17",
            "Longitude": "78",
            "RecordedDateTime": "1254"
        },
        "-Kci77tuFbWP5Vdt4keF": {
            "Latitude": "17",
            "Longitude": "78",
            "RecordedDateTime": "1254"
        }
    },  
    "MobileNumber": 1234567890,
    "UserName": "Firstname Lastname"
}
```

my firebase query from java returns a DataSnapshot which I know contains the above structure. I have the following Java object which I think maps to the above structure.

```
public class User {
    private String EmailId;
    private String MobileNumber;
    private String UserName;
    private ArrayList<UserLocationInfo> userLocationInfos;

    //Constructor, getters and setters are below.
}
```

But the code fails whenever I try to read the DataSnapshot into this object using the following code.

```
dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class)
```

Error:

```
com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Failed to convert value of type java.lang.Long to String.
```

Please advise on the Java class and also why am I getting this convertion error when Firebase stores data as json whose values are Strings?

Comment: change ArrayList... to Map<String, Object> Locations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your MobileNumber was saved as a long value and you're trying to retrieve it as a String. You can change it's data type on your POJO:

```
public class User {
    private String EmailId;
    private long MobileNumber;
    private String UserName;
    private ArrayList<UserLocationInfo> userLocationInfos;

    //Constructor, getters and setters are below.
}
```

Or turning into a String on your Database, by adding quotation marks:

```
"MobileNumber": "1234567890",
"UserName": "Firstname Lastname"
```

Comment: I though once data goes into key value pair DB, it becomes a string

Comment: Yes, the whole database is a single JSON file (which is basically a structured string). But when you're writing and/or reading data, the data must have a specific data type. You can see all supported data types [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#basic_write).

Comment: will the inner list be mapped to the ArrayList variable in the java class.

Comment: I've never tried using ArrayLists on firebase, but as @Linxy mentioed, you should change it to `Map<String, Object>`